# How to display auto complete text only when the user has typed @

Tags: c#

I have a datagrid in csharp windows application. I want to display autocomplete text only when the user has typed @. Just like how we do in FB comment box. Below is the code that I am using for autocomplete now

```
private void dgv_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs
{
 TextBox autoText = e.Control as TextBox;
 if (autoText != null)
 {
  autoText.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;                    
  autoText.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
  autoText.AutoCompleteCustomSource = inputFields;
 }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with *now*? How *we do in FB comment box*?

Comment: If my input fields contains jill,jack,harry as auto complete text, Then the auto complete would come only if the textbox starts with j or h. But in Facebook comment box.I get the username where ever we type @.

My requirement is I need to show some list only when the user types @ and at any position in the textbox

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your point, this code may be helpful:

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{              
     TextBox autoText = e.Control as TextBox;
     autoText.TextChanged += autoText_TextChanged;
}

void autoText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     TextBox autoText = sender as TextBox;
     if (autoText != null && autoText.Text[0] == '@')
     {
          autoText.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
          autoText.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
          var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
          source.AddRange(new string[] { "@MyValue" });
          autoText.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;
     }
}
```

You should bind new event then compare the `TextBox` value and do your stuff.

**UPDATE**
Change the code to this:

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
     TextBox autoText = e.Control as TextBox;
     autoText.KeyPress += autoText_KeyPress;
}

void autoText_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
     TextBox autoText = sender as TextBox;
     if (autoText.Text.Length == 0 && e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back)
     {
          autoText.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None;
     }
     if (autoText.Text.Length == 0 && e.KeyChar == '@')
     {
          autoText.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
          autoText.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
          var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
          source.AddRange(new string[] { "MyValue" }); //values that should appear in the autocomplete
          autoText.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;
          e.Handled = true;
     }
}
```

If the first input letter is '@', `Autocompelete mode` switches on and if you're pressing `Backspace` until the Textbox being empty, `Autocompelete Mode` switches off.

Comment: but here will the the autocomplete list will show @MyValue or only MyValue

Comment: also my autocomplete show appear whenever I type @ at any position